# Extract and load only new records

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have simple SSIS data flow which extract records from table A and load them to the table B.  Table A and Table B has unique key.

What is the best way to extract and load only new records?

Comment: Are TableA and TableB in the same DB/on the same server?

Comment: Table A on the linked server of Table B

Comment: What are these unique keys and are they different from each other? Rather...could you give us more information on the table structures? It'll really help us in giving you a good answer. How are the unique keys generated? Is it an identity seed set column? Is it numeric or alphanumeric? Aside from all the columns in TableA(source) that should be in TableB(destination), is there anything else that exists in TableB that doesn't exist in TableA?

Comment: In my case I have many tables TableA1..100 and TablesB1..100, so I am searching as general solution as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the [LOOKUP-task solution](http://blog.raffaeu.com/archive/2008/06/20/sql-ssis-insert-only-new-rows.aspx), but I am still searching another good solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A)if records are on sequential unique key, check the max record in table B and then select record from table A greater than this value.

B)After each row of iteration, save the unique key in some table/xml file. Use this value at the start of task to select records from table A.